# How to make a sub group form a group in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I made a filter to count each posiiton at a lane.

```
 filterd_df = df.groupby(['place_id', 'position_id'])['position_id'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
place_id  position
1        1               1234
         2               7000
         3               8000
         4               10000

2        6               4111
         7               9875
         8               9900
         9               1000
```

I want to group in order the positions to another group 'locations'. So position 1 becomes location 1, 2 becomes 2 etc. Also with place 2 I want to do the same so that 6 becomes location 1 etc.

How do group them?

I was trying with the.groupby, cumcount() and cumsum() function, but it did not help does someone have a solution?

Comment: Your question is missing a [mre]. Please provide a small input DataFrame as example and the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for:

```py
import pandas as pd

multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9)], names=['place_id', 'position'])

data = [[1234], [7000], [8000], [10000], [4111], [9875], [9900], [1000]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=multi_index, columns=['value'])

def map_position_to_location(row):
    place_id, position = row.name
    if place_id == 1:
        return position
    elif place_id == 2:
        return position - 5

df['location'] = df.apply(map_position_to_location, axis=1)
print(df)
```

to adjust it to your code:

```
def map_position_to_location(row):
    place_id, position = row.name
    if place_id == 1:
        return position
    elif place_id == 2:
        return position - 5

filterd_df['location'] = filterd_df.apply(map_position_to_location, axis=1)
print(filterd_df)
```

Comment: hey,

Yes! But can you explain me the logic of your code? Because i get the error:     duration_position['location'] = duration_position.apply(map_position_to_location, axis=1)
If i use it on my code

Comment: how does duration_position df look like? what is the error

Comment: This is the error
TypeError: main.<locals>.map_position_to_location() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: please make sure you are using a dataframe, print(type(df)) etc to see

Comment: This is my filter what i made i want to plot the locations but i needed first to find the positions per lane.

filterd_df = df.groupby(['place_id', 'position_id'])['position_id'].value_counts()

Comment: Is a pandacore series <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: did you try this: `filtered_df = filtered_df.set_index(['place_id', 'position_id'])`

Comment: Where do i need to add the code?

Comment: after this: ` filterd_df = df.groupby(['place_id', 'position_id'])['position_id'].value_counts()`

Comment: I get this error:
 AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'. Did you mean: 'reset_index'?